# Prevent quad view from resetting?

Tags: 3d-view, workflow, shortcut

Is there a way to prevent the quad view (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) from resetting?

I'm using the quad view with the "Lock" option disabled. Each time I maximize and minimize a viewport in the quad view, the top right viewport gets reset and becomes the last view I was in.

Answer (score 4):

NO, it's not possible: modified quad views reset to the default if you exit quad view.

A workaround would be to create a new screen layout that has your modified quad view.

[image]